# What's the best way to process array of JSON messages posted to Nodejs server?

Tags: web-services, api, node.js, asynchronous

A client sends an array of JSON messages to be stored at Nodejs server; but client will require some sort of acknowledgement for each message (through unique id), that it was properly stored at server, and hence doesn't need to be sent again.

At server I want to parse the JSON array, then loop through it, store each message in db, store response for this message in JSON array named responses, and finally send this responses array to the client. But as the db operations are async, all other code is executed before any result returned from db storing methods. My question is how to keep updating the responses array, untill all db operations are complete?

```
var message = require('./models/message');
var async = require('async');

var VALID_MESSAGE = 200;
var INVALID_MESSAGE = 400;
var SERVER_ERROR = 500;

function processMessage(passedMessage, callback) { 
var msg = null;
var err = null;  
var responses = [];

isValidMessage(passedMessage, function(err, result) {
if(err) {
  callback( createResponse(INVALID_MESSAGE, 0) );
}else{ 
 var keys = Object.keys(result);
for(var i=0, len = keys.length; i<len; i++) {
async.waterfall([     
  //store valid json message(s)
  function storeMessage(callback) {   
    (function(oneMessage) {
      message.processMessage(result[i], function(res) {
        callback(res, result[i].mid, callback);  
      });
    })(result[i]);
    console.log('callback returns from storeMessage()');
  },

  //create a json response to send back to client
  function createResponse(responseCode, mid, callback) {
    var status = "";
    var msg = "";

    switch(responseCode) {
    case VALID_MESSAGE: { 
      status = "pass";
      msg = "Message stored successfuly.";
      break;
    }
    case INVALID_MESSAGE: {
      status = "fail";
      msg = "Message invalid, please send again with correct data.";
      break;
    }
    case SERVER_ERROR: {
      status = "fail";
      msg = "Internal Server Error! please contact the administrator.";
      break;
    }
    default: {

      responseCode = SERVER_ERROR;
      status = "fail";
      msg = "Internal Server Error! please contact the administrator.";
      break;
    }
  }
  var response = { "mid": mid, "status": status, "message": msg, "code": responseCode};   
  callback(null, response );   
  }                     
],

function(err, result) {
  console.log('final callback in series: ', result);
  responses.push(result);          
});
}//loop ends
}//else ends
console.log('now we can send response back to app as: ', responses);  
});//isValid finishes
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on what lanzz said, this is a pretty common solution (start a number of "tasks" all at the same time, and then use a common callback to determine when they're all done). Here's a quick paste of my function from my userStats function, which gets the number of active users (DAU, WAU, and HAU):

```
exports.userStats = function(app, callback)
{
    var res = {'actives': {}},
       day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
       req_model = Request.alloc(app).model,
       actives = {'DAU': day, 'MAU': day*31, 'WAU': day*7},
       countActives = function(name, time) {
           var date = new Date(new Date().getTime() - time);
           req_model.distinct('username',{'date': {$gte: date}}, function(e,c){ 
               res.actives[name] = parseInt(c ? c.length : 0, 10);
               if(Object.keys(actives).length <= Object.keys(res.actives).length)
                   callback(null, res);
           });
       };


    var keys = Object.keys(actives);
    for(var k in keys)
    {
        countActives(keys[k], actives[keys[k]]);
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks for the example, now on every return from db model, I check the keys lengths before final callback and it has worked.

Answer (score 1):

Only send your `responses` array when the number of items in it equals the number of keys in your `result` object (i.e. you've gathered responses for all of them). You can check if you're good to send after you push each response in the array.